# Many to one relationship search and serialization in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am kinda new to Django and trying to understand how I can search in different models and create nested serializer.
This is the simple model file that I have

```
   class Company(models.Model):
        company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        mail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
        NIF = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True, blank=True)
        

class Office(models.Model):
        company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
        office_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Main')
        direction = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        

class Employee(models.Model):
        office = models.ForeignKey(Office)
        employee_ name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        mail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
```

here the company has many offices and offices have many employees. So I am creating a search API in which a user can search the company_name or office_name or employee name and get the data in a relational format like this;

```
company: {
    -------
    office: {
        ------
        Employee: {
            ------
        }
    }
}
```

now my problem is filtering the data and serializing it in this format. I tried this [Nested Serialization](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) for serialization and also tried filter from here [filter in django](https://davit.tech/django-queryset-examples/) but not able to come up with the solution.

Note: I am creating Django API by using django-rest-framework

Comment: If you want to have this format, you must override `to_representation()`. However,  ManyToOne will give you always a list e.g. {"company": [{"office_1": {"employee": [ {"key": "value"}, {"key": "value"}]}}, {"office_2": {}}]}`

Comment: You can filter in serializer, but it is not a regular approach. You should filter your objects in your view to get querysets or instance. Add your instance data to your serializer and get your serialized data.

Comment: Could you add your serializer for a better understanding?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) in multiple serializers to implement the above data format.

For example:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    office = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    ...
    
    def get_office(self, obj):
        return OfficeSerializer(obj.office_set.all(), many=True).data


class OfficeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    employee = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    ...
    
    def get_employee(self, obj):
        return EmployeeSerializer(obj.employee_set.all(), many=True).data
    
    
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    ...
```

You can use [django_filters](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) for filtering